# I need to sort out the theta complexity for lg(n^(1/2))

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence-relation

Can you help me find the theta complexity for lg(n^(1/2))?

Comment: $\Theta(\log n^{42})$. Also $\Theta(\log n^c)$ for any constant $c>0$ of your choice.

Answer (score 1):

$log(n^{\frac{1}{2}}) = \frac{1}{2}log(n) = \theta(log(n))$.

More formally, there exists constants $c1$,$c2$ such that:

$c1⋅\frac{1}{2}log(n)≤log(n)≤c2⋅\frac{1}{2}log(n)$

Answer (score 0):

A valid answer is

$$\lg(\sqrt n)=\Theta(\lg(\sqrt n)).$$

This is true as of $n=1$ with constants $1$.

Another valid answer is

$$\lg(\sqrt n)=\Theta\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1k\right).$$

(Holds as of $n=2$ with constants $0.2$ and $1$.)